# Private methods, inheritance, and meta programing?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have the following defined:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Something
  def self._attr_accessor key, value, type
    (class << self; self; end).send( :attr_accessor, key.to_sym)
    instance_variable_set "@#{key}", value
  end
end

class Client < Something
  _attr_accessor 'foo_bar', 'json', String
end

my_something = Client.new
puts my_something.foo_bar
```

But I recieve the following error:

```
/test_inheritance.rb:18:in `<class:Client>': undefined method `foo_bar' for Client:Class (NoMethodError)
    from ./test_inheritance.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

The bit of metaprograming I am doing works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
class Something
  def self._attr_accessor key, value, type
    (class << self; self; end).send( :attr_accessor, key.to_sym)
    instance_variable_set "@#{key}", value
  end
end

class Client < Something
  _attr_accessor 'foo_bar', 'json', String

  puts self.foo_bar
end

my_something = Client.new

#puts my_something.foo_bar
```

As it outputs the proper result.  But how do I define the _attr_accessor methods such that I am able to access it methods publicly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one I think you're tripping over the fact that `format` is a reserved method on `Class` and it's conflicting with your `attr_accessor` attempt.

Secondly there's a better way to do this. I've made a fairly robust "accessor" utility class for a project I'm working on. It allows you to define class-level defaults and still override instance definitions.

The implementation looks like this:

```
module OptionAccessor
  # Given a list of names, this declares an option accessor which works like
  # a combination of cattr_accessor and attr_accessor, except that defaults
  # defined for a class will propagate down to the instances and subclasses,
  # but these defaults can be over-ridden in subclasses and instances
  # without interference. Optional hash at end of list can be used to set:
  #  * :default => Assigns a default value which is otherwise nil
  #  * :boolean => If true, creates an additional name? method and will
  #                convert all assigned values to a boolean true/false.
  def option_accessor(*args)
    option_reader(*args)
    option_writer(*args)
  end

  # Given a list of names, this declares an option reader which works like
  # a combination of cattr_reader and attr_reader, except that defaults
  # defined for a class will propagate down to the instances and subclasses,
  # but these defaults can be over-ridden in subclasses and instances
  # without interference. Optional hash at end of list can be used to set:
  #  * :default => Assigns a default value which is otherwise nil
  #  * :boolean => If true, creates an additional name? method and will
  #                convert all assigned values to a boolean true/false.
  def option_reader(*names)
    names = [ names ].flatten.compact
    options = names.last.is_a?(Hash) ? names.pop : { }

    names.each do |name|
      iv = :"@#{name}"

      (class << self; self; end).class_eval do
        if (options[:boolean])
          define_method(:"#{name}?") do
            iv_value = instance_variable_get(iv)

            !!(iv_value.nil? ? (self.superclass.respond_to?(name) ? self.superclass.send(name) : nil) : iv_value)
          end
        end

        define_method(name) do
          iv_value = instance_variable_get(iv)

          iv_value.nil? ? (self.superclass.respond_to?(name) ? self.superclass.send(name) : nil) : iv_value
        end
      end

      define_method(name) do
        iv_value = instance_variable_get(iv)

        iv_value.nil? ? self.class.send(name) : iv_value
      end

      if (options[:boolean])
        define_method(:"#{name}?") do
          iv_value = instance_variable_get(iv)

          !!(iv_value.nil? ? self.class.send(name) : iv_value)
        end
      end

      instance_variable_set(iv, options[:default])
    end
  end

  # Given a list of names, this declares an option writer which works like
  # a combination of cattr_writer and attr_writer, except that defaults
  # defined for a class will propagate down to the instances and subclasses,
  # but these defaults can be over-ridden in subclasses and instances
  # without interference. Options can be specified:
  #  * :boolean => If true, converts all supplied values to true or false
  #                unless nil, in which case nil is preserved.
  def option_writer(*names)
    names = [ names ].flatten.compact
    options = names.last.is_a?(Hash) ? names.pop : { }

    names.each do |name|
      iv = :"@#{name}"

      (class << self; self; end).class_eval do
        if (options[:boolean])
          define_method(:"#{name}=") do |value|
            instance_variable_set(iv, value.nil? ? nil : !!value)
          end
        else
          define_method(:"#{name}=") do |value|
            instance_variable_set(iv, value)
          end
        end
      end

      if (options[:boolean])
        define_method(:"#{name}=") do |value|
          instance_variable_set(iv, value.nil? ? nil : !!value)
        end
      else
        define_method(:"#{name}=") do |value|
          instance_variable_set(iv, value)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, do you have any example use cases?

Comment: also, changing the metod from `format` to `foobar` I run into and undeclared issues when called outside the class and similarly to how I originally described it works fine when called within the class indicating a private method declaration.  If you could explain to me why the method is being declared private I would greatly appreciate it too!

Comment: An example is to just put `option_accessor :foo` in a class. Then you can call `MyClass.foo` or `MyClass.new.foo` and so forth, even with assignment via `MyClass.foo = 'foo'`.

Comment: The method wasn't being declared, but there was a pre-existing method with the same name that was already private. That was probably the issue.

Comment: There is something about the manor which it is defined which only allows access to the method declared within the class it self (i.e. `self.foo` inside the class works but outside it does not.). Your response does not answer my question but I voted you up none the less for your excellent response. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your method with:

```
class Something

  def self._attr_accessor key, value, type
    method_sym      = key.to_sym
    insance_variable = "@#{key}"

    (class << self; self; end).send( :attr_accessor, method_sym)
    instance_variable_set insance_variable, value

    attr_accessor method_sym

    define_method(method_sym) do 
        self.instance_variable_get(insance_variable) or self.class.send(method_sym) 
    end

  end

 end
```

---

```
 define_method(method_sym) do 
    self.instance_variable_get(insance_variable) or self.class.send(method_sym) 
 end
```

in the above code, **define_method** is define a instance method for Someting, method name is key, such as

```
 attr_accessor "foo_bar", "json", String
```

then the **define_method** generated code is:

```
 def foo_bar
    if @foo_bar
       @foo_bar
    else
      self.class.foo_bar
    end        
 end
```

in addition to, ActiveSupport has  **attr_accessor_with_default** method, seems also be this function.
Please refer to it's code:

```
class Module
# Declare an attribute accessor with an initial default return value.t>:
#
#   class Person
#     attr_accessor_with_default :age, 25
#   end
#
#   person = Person.new
#   person.age # => 25
#
# To give attribute <tt>:element_name</tt> a dynamic default value, evaluated
# in scope of self:
#
#   attr_accessor_with_default(:element_name) { name.underscore }
#
def attr_accessor_with_default(sym, default = Proc.new)
  define_method(sym, block_given? ? default : Proc.new { default })
  module_eval(<<-EVAL, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1)
    def #{sym}=(value)
      class << self; attr_accessor :#{sym} end
      @#{sym} = value
    end
  EVAL
end
end
```

Comment: This gets rid of my error but still I am not able to access the methods as if the were defined using attr_accessor.  My whole objective is to bootstrap the preexisting methods with one which I am able to define a default for for which.

Comment: Also I am really not sure what is happening in the `defin_method` block, could you explain that to me?